# trying to schedule task on workstation lock windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a powershell script that mute or unmute my computer on workstation lock and unlock

the powershell script have read & execute permissions for 'users'

when I run the script manually from the Task Scheduler it works, when I lock or unlock my machine nothing happens.

Thanks!

the powershell script:

```
$wshShell = new-object -com wscript.shell
$wshShell.SendKeys([char]0xAD)
```

this is the task XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2018-01-26T15:03:46.4215634</Date>
    <Author>ERAN-PC\Eran</Author>
    <URI>\Mute or UnmuteComputer</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <SessionStateChangeTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <StateChange>SessionLock</StateChange>
    </SessionStateChangeTrigger>
    <SessionStateChangeTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <StateChange>SessionUnlock</StateChange>
    </SessionStateChangeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <GroupId>S-1-5-32-545</GroupId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>powershell</Command>
      <Arguments>-file "E:\Documents\mutepc.ps1"</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory>E:\Documents</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Users\Eran\Desktop\checkpoint\hide and seek\secret.png"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: When you say that nothing happened, what do you mean? Did the task run? (Check the event logs.) Was the script executed? (Give the script a side effect, like writing a timestamp to a file or logging an event.) Did the volume get muted? (Play an audio file.)

Comment: Looks like restart to my machine fixed the issue...